# How to display DataGridView rows in blocks - Visual C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a program that gets data from a MySQL Database and displays it to a DataGridView. Because each row is an app that can be downloaded, I want each row to be displayed in it's own little block. Here's a little sketch of what I want:[image]

Each box shown is a row. Each section (Icon, app name, description, downloadbtn) is a column.
Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: For that purpose use `ListView` control ... link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx

Comment: Don't use `DataGridView` for that.

Comment: @nelek any idea how to bind MySQL data from MySQL connector to a ListView?

Comment: ListViews are jagged arrays and don't bind easily. You can always try to ownerdraw the Cells in the CellPainting event..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListViews` don't support `DataBinding` and while `DataGridviews` do they only display a matrix of rows and columns, so they can't display row data side by side.

I suggest do away with your `DataGridview`.

Instead you tie the data  to a suitable other container which you fill with a `UserControl` that display your data. An `AutoScrolling` `FlowLayoutPanel` is probably the best choice.

So you create a `UserControl`, called, say `DataBox`, add a few `Labels` and the `Button` and an extra constructor that can load the data from a `DataTable.DataRow`.

Then you code a loading function that creates a new `DataBox` for each row in the table and loads its fields into your Labels.

Then you call the function from all spots where the data change like maybe the `RowChanged` event of the `DataTable`..

Here is a minimal example class:

[image]

```
public delegate void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e);

public partial class DataBox : UserControl
{
    public DataRow row  { get; set; }

    public ButtonClick ButtonClick { private get; set; }

    public DataBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public DataBox(DataRow row)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        loadRow(row);
        button1.GotFocus += (s, e) => { BackColor = Color.SkyBlue; };
        button1.LostFocus += (s, e) => { BackColor = Color.Azure; };
    }

    public void loadRow(DataRow row_)
    {
        if (row_ == null || row_.ItemArray.Length < 3) return;
        row = row_;
        label1.Text = row.ItemArray[0].ToString();
        label2.Text = row.ItemArray[1].ToString();
        label3.Text = row.ItemArray[2].ToString();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ButtonClick != null) ButtonClick(sender, e);
    }
}
```

When data change the display will refresh:

```
private void DT_RowChanged(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
{
    loadBoxes();
}
```

This is a loading function, which loads all rows in the table:

```
void loadBoxes()
{
    List<DataBox> boxes = new List<DataBox>();
    foreach (DataRow row in DT.Rows)
        boxes.Add(new DataBox(row) { ButtonClick = boxButton_Click } );
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.AddRange(boxes.ToArray());
    boxes.Clear();
}
```

The `Buttons` are calling a central click processing function in you form:

```
private void boxButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    DataBox box = btn.Parent as DataBox;
    if (box != null)
        Console.WriteLine(box.rowID + " clicked");
}
```

But of course you may instead code their click right in the `DataBox` class..

You may want to improve on a few other points, like updating single rows or making the `Labels` send focus to the `Button`, thus causing the `BackColor` to show the 'selection'..